# Ограничение доступа к данным по организациям

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Подскажите пожалуйста, никак не могу найти информацию касаемо ограничения доступа к базе данных определенной группе пользователей.

У меня есть сущность пользователей и организаций.
Каждый пользователь относится к определенной организации.
Каждая организация имеет свой уникальный id.

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_organization_id"))
private Organization organization;
```

Я хочу чтоб пользователи видели данные только своей организации.
Как это можно реализовать в srping?

Comment: Spring security - смотрите туда

Comment: Ну это понятно что туда смотреть, для этого я и спрашиваю как это реализовать :)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring

Comment: Спасибо) retrieve user information самое то)